# Simulate shell using linked lists

Tags: c, shell, memory, malloc

Now i'm learning C and I have a problem with memory alocation, atleast this I understand from my code error.

Code

```
#ifndef __FILE_H__
#define __FILE_H__

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Files Files;
typedef struct DirList DirList;
typedef struct NodeFile NodeFile;
typedef struct NodeDir NodeDir;

typedef struct Directory {
    // The name of the directory
    char *name;

    //  The list of files of the current directory
    Files *files;

    // The list of dirs of the current directory
    DirList *dirs;

    // The parent directory of the current directory (NULL for the root
    // directory)
    struct Directory *parentDir;
} Directory;


typedef struct File {
    // The name of the file
    char *name;

    // The size of the file
    int size;

    // The content of the file
    char *data;

    // The directory in which the file is located
    Directory *dir;
} File;

typedef struct Files {
    NodeFile *first;
    NodeFile *last;
} Files;

typedef struct DirList {
    NodeDir *first;
    NodeDir *last;
} DirList;

typedef struct NodeFile {
    struct NodeFile *next;
    struct NodeFile *prev;
    File *newfile;
} NodeFile;

typedef struct NodeDir {
    struct NodeDir *next;
    struct NodeDir *prev;
    Directory *newdir;
} NodeDir;

// create root of file system
void makeroot(Directory **root)
{
    *root = (Directory *) malloc(sizeof(Directory));

    (*root)->parentDir = NULL;
    (*root)->name = "/";
    (*root)->files = NULL;
    (*root)->dirs = NULL;
}

// remove root of file system
void deleteroot(Directory *root)
{
    root = NULL;
    free(root);
}

//add new file to current directory
File *touch(Directory *root, char *nume, char *content)
{
    NodeFile *new = (NodeFile *) malloc(sizeof(NodeFile));

    new->newfile = (File *) malloc(sizeof(File));

    new->newfile->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

    new->newfile->data = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

    strcpy(new->newfile->name, nume);
    strcpy(new->newfile->data, content);

    if (root->files == NULL) {
        root->files = (Files *) malloc(sizeof(Files));
        root->files->first = (NodeFile *) malloc(sizeof(NodeFile));
        root->files->last = (NodeFile *) malloc(sizeof(NodeFile));
        //if no file in folder root has first and last position
        root->files->first = new;
        root->files->last = new;
    } else if (strcmp(root->files->first->newfile->name,
                        new->newfile->name) > 0) {
        new->next = root->files->first;
        root->files->first = new;
    } else if (strcmp(root->files->last->newfile->name,
                        new->newfile->name) < 0) {
        root->files->last->next = new;
        root->files->last = new;
    } else {
        NodeFile *i = root->files->first;

        while (i != root->files->last) {
            if (strcmp(i->next->newfile->name,
                    new->newfile->name) > 0) {
                if (i == root->files->first->next)
                    i = root->files->first;
                i->next->prev = new;
                new->next = i->next;
                new->prev = i;
                i->next = new;
                break;
            }
            i = i->next;
        }
    }
    return new->newfile;
}

// Create directory
Directory *mkdir(Directory *parent, char *name)
{
    // la fel ca la touch
    NodeDir *new = (NodeDir *) malloc(sizeof(NodeDir));

    new->newdir = (Directory *) malloc(sizeof(Directory));

    new->newdir->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

    strcpy(new->newdir->name, name);
    new->newdir->parentDir = parent;

    if (parent->dirs == NULL) {
        parent->dirs = (DirList *)malloc(sizeof(DirList));
        parent->dirs->first = (NodeDir *) malloc(sizeof(NodeDir));
        parent->dirs->last = (NodeDir *) malloc(sizeof(NodeDir));
        parent->dirs->first = new;
        parent->dirs->last = new;
    } else if (strcmp(parent->dirs->first->newdir->name,
                        new->newdir->name) > 0) {
        new->next = parent->dirs->first;
        parent->dirs->first = new;
    } else if (strcmp(parent->dirs->last->newdir->name,
                        new->newdir->name) < 0) {
        parent->dirs->last->next = new;
        parent->dirs->last = new;
    } else {
        NodeDir *i = parent->dirs->first->next;

        while (i != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(i->newdir->name, new->newdir->name) > 0) {
                if (i == parent->dirs->first->next)
                    i = parent->dirs->first;
                i->next->prev = new;
                new->next = i->next;
                new->prev = i;
                i->next = new;
                break;
            }
            i = i->next;
        }
    }
    return new->newdir;
}

// traverse list and print files and folders names
void ls(Directory *parent)
{
    if (parent->files != NULL) {
        NodeFile *i;

        for (i = parent->files->first; i != NULL; i = i->next)
            printf("%s ", i->newfile->name);
        free(i);
    }

    if (parent->dirs != NULL) {
        NodeDir *j;

        for (j = parent->dirs->first; j != NULL; j = j->next)
            printf("%s ", j->newdir->name);
        free(j);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

// working directory
void pwd(Directory *dir)
{
    if (dir->parentDir == NULL)
        return;
    if (dir->parentDir != NULL) {
        pwd(dir->parentDir);
        printf("/%s", dir->name);
    }
}


Directory *cd(Directory *dir, char *where)
{
    if (strcmp(where, "..") == 0 && dir->parentDir != NULL) {
        return dir->parentDir;
    } else if (dir->dirs == NULL)
        printf("Cannot move to ‘%s’: No such directory!\n", where);
    else {
        NodeDir *it = dir->dirs->first;

        while (it != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(it->newdir->name, where) == 0) {
                dir = it->newdir;
                break;
            }
            it = it->next;
        }
        if (it == NULL)
            printf("Cannot move to ‘%s’: No such directory!\n",
                    where);
        free(it);
    }
    return dir;
}

void tree(Directory *parent, int i)
{

    if (i == 1)
        printf("\n%s\n", parent->name);
    if (parent->files != NULL) {
        NodeFile *it;

        for (it = parent->files->first; it != NULL; it = it->next) {
            if (i != 1) {
                int j;

                for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    printf("   ");
            }
            printf("   %s\n", it->newfile->name);
        }
        free(it);
    }
    if (parent->dirs != NULL) {
        NodeDir *it = parent->dirs->first;

        while (it != NULL) {

            int j;

            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                printf("   ");
            printf("%s\n", it->newdir->name);
            i = i + 1;
            tree(it->newdir, i);
            it = it->next;
            i = i - 1;
        }
        free(it);
    }
}


void rm(Directory *parent, char *dirname)
{ //it -- item
    NodeFile *it;

    for (it = parent->files->first; it != NULL; it = it->next) {
        if (strcmp(it->newfile->name, dirname) == 0) {
            if (it == parent->files->first) {
                parent->files->first =
                parent->files->first->next;
            } else if (it == parent->files->last) {
                parent->files->last = it->prev;
            } else {
                it->prev->next = it->next;
                it->next->prev = it->prev;
            }
            it = NULL;
            free(it);
            return;
        }
    }
    if (it == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot remove ‘%s’: No such file!\n", dirname);
        free(it);
    }
}


void rmdir(Directory *parent, char *dirname)
{

    NodeDir *it;

    for (it = parent->dirs->first; it != NULL; it = it->next) {
        if (strcmp(it->newdir->name, dirname) == 0) {
            if (it == parent->dirs->first) {
                parent->dirs->first =
                parent->dirs->first->next;
            } else if (it == parent->dirs->last) {
                parent->dirs->last =
                parent->dirs->last->prev;
            } else {
                it->prev->next = it->next;
                it->next->prev = it->prev;
            }
            it = NULL;
            free(it);
            return;
        }
    }
    if (it == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot remove ‘%s’: No such directory!\n", dirname);
        free(it);
    }
}

#endif
```

And this is the output of my execution
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes  --error-exitcode=1 ./shell

```
  touch x
==6012== Invalid write of size 1
==6012==    at 0x4C32E0D: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6012==    by 0x108ACA: touch (file.h:94)
==6012==    by 0x109746: main (main.c:83)
==6012==  Address 0x522d8f1 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==6012==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6012==    by 0x108A97: touch (file.h:90)
==6012==    by 0x109746: main (main.c:83)
==6012== 
==6012== Invalid write of size 1
==6012==    at 0x4C32E0D: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6012==    by 0x108AE5: touch (file.h:95)
==6012==    by 0x109746: main (main.c:83)
==6012==  Address 0x522d941 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==6012==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6012==    by 0x108AAC: touch (file.h:92)
==6012==    by 0x109746: main (main.c:83)
```

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: fyi, `root = NULL; free(root);` though legal, is a recipe for a memory leak. IN fact, the only time it isn't is when `root` was null on entry.

Comment: regarding: `__FILE_H__`  a leading __<capital letter> sequence is 'reserved' for the system  Suggest removing the leading underscores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not allocate enough for your string in *touch*

```
new->newfile->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
new->newfile->data = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

*name* and *date* have place for only one char, in case of a 'standard' string that means you can only handle empty strings (only the null character to end them)

```
strcpy(new->newfile->name, nume);
strcpy(new->newfile->data, content);
```

it is enough *nume* and *content* have 1 char then the terminating null char to write out of the allocated strings, valgrind indicates this is the case

You have the same problem in *mkdir*

To easily both allocate and copy use *strdup*, else allocate *strlen(xx) + 1* to duplicate *xx*, so replace

> ```
> new->newfile->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
> new->newfile->data = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
>
> strcpy(new->newfile->name, nume);
> strcpy(new->newfile->data, content);
> ```

by

```
new->newfile->name = strdup(nume);
new->newfile->data = strdup(content);
```

or

```
 new->newfile->name = (char *) malloc(strlen(nume) + 1);
 new->newfile->data = (char *) malloc(strlen(content) + 1);

 strcpy(new->newfile->name, nume);
 strcpy(new->newfile->data, content);
```

and do the same in *mkdir*

---

in *makeroot* you do

> ```
> (*root)->name = "/";
> ```

this is dangerous because if you want to free the resources you have to remember to not try to free *(*root)->name* to not have an undefined behavior, to not take that risk I encourage you to also duplicate "/"

```
(*root)->name = strdup("/");
```

---

In *deleteroot* you do nothing because you set *root* to NULL then free, so you have memory leaks. You need to free all the resources you allocated, so you have to go through all the tree.

You have the same problem in *rm*.

Each time you had an allocation you need a free

---

in *ls* do not free resources, only print

---

It seems all the code you give is placed in a header file, only place struct definitions and function *declarations* in header files, move function *definitions* in a source file else if you include several time that header file you will have the functions defined several times

Comment: Both. Touch and mkdir have the same errors of memory allocation. Thank you for your answer.  I will try to alocate more. I'm learning.

Comment: @georgian yes I know, and indicate that in my answer

Comment: @georgian do you understand what I say in my answer ?

Comment: Sorry  for my answer. Yes. I understood what you said. Now I'm trying to figure out how to implement it.

Comment: you saved my life with your examples and was very explicit. now i'm encountered another problem on "ls".

Comment: @georgian yes I see you do free in *ls*, remove these free

Comment: ls
==9103== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9103==    at 0x109025: ls (file.h:193)
==9103==    by 0x1097CC: main (main.c:86)
==9103==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==9103==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9103==    by 0x108D44: mkdir (file.h:136)
==9103==    by 0x10975E: main (main.c:81)

Comment: @georgian I do not have your new version, I cannot know the code at the lines given by valgrind, but it is easy for you to see the missing initialization thanks to messages of valgrind

Comment: I have added my updated code. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @georgian you already accepted my answer and now you have an other problem, please remove your edit with the updated code and open a new question, it will be more clear and easy to follow

Comment: Thank you. I can't post another question 90 minutes from now. Anyway. Was a big help from you.

Comment: @georgian ok I looked more and in *mkdir* you do not set the fields *files* nor *dirs* of your new *Directory*, in *touch* you miss to set *new->next* to NULL in some cases etc. To simplify your code and makes it robust I encourage you to add for each struct a constructor doing the malloc and initializing all the fields with NULL/default value, and also add a destructor for each

Comment: @georgian you can also allocate using *calloc* rather than *malloc* in your case considering the definitions of your structs, but this is lazy and do not solve the way to free resources

Comment: I created a new question @  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60913495/shell-simulation-using-lists